# How can I resolve the 'Invalid table alias or column name' error in HIVE while creating a table?

Tags: sql, hive, impala

I am trying to create a table in HIVE, however it's not recognising table alias
not sure how can I fix this, this is my code.

```
drop table if exist data_pull_0526;
create table data_pull_0526 as
select distinct
y.a,
y.b,
y.c
from bon y
where y.a='cash'
and y.c in (select distinct z.acct from table z);
```

Error Cloudera{hardy} syntax or semantic analysis error...Invalid table alias or column name

How to fix above error

Comment: Then don't use a table alias

Comment: what if there are multiple subqueries then I have to use table alias.

Comment: yes, alias everything in select clause. Hope the answer below gives some solution.

Comment: **from table z** Do you really have a table called "table"?

Answer (score 0):

The best idea would be alias every column in select clause. Pls follow below SQL -

```
drop table if exist data_pull_0526;
create table data_pull_0526 as
select distinct
y.a as col_a,
y.b as col_b,
y.c as col_c,
x.foo as col_x_foo
from bon y
left join x on x.id = y.id
where y.a='cash'
and y.c in (select distinct z.acct from table z);
```